# What does the operand of this mov instruction underlined in this image mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

[image]

The above image along with the title fully encapsulates my question :-)

Extra details (if necessary):
I assume the above is enough information to answer the question, so if you know the answer and you wish to stop reading the rest of the question, that's totally fine.

I'm trying to understand what happens when a struct is returned by a C function. This is an example from the ``Reverse Engineering for Beginners'' by Dennis Yurichev page 139 (Returning a struct).

I understand that _a$ and $T3853 are macros, but I don't understand what the instruction actually does after the macros are replaced by their values.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.  Instead, [edit] your question and post the code as text.

Comment: @fuz my bad, that makes it harder for people to copy-paste things. I'll definitely do that for my next posts, as you've fully answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See above, `_a$` and `$T3853` are symbols defined to value 12 and 8 respectively.  So

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
```

is the same as

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR 12[esp-4]
```

or

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esp-4+12]
```

or

```
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
```

Comment: May I ask, for these kinds of questions, is there some sort of reference document that can easily be checked? Or do you gain this sort of knowledge from experience and asking people?

Comment: @Horace MSVC uses the syntax of MASM, the Microsoft Assembler.  Read its manual to understand the assembly syntax.  As for the instructions, refer to the Intel Software Development Manuals for their definitions.